# Add strings to List<string[]> list

Tags: c#, .net

I'm new to C#, I need to do the following:

I need to declare a List

```
List<string[]> myList = new List<string[]>();
```

Now the conditions and adding to the list should work as follows (in pseudo code):

```
for int i = 0 to N
if nNumber == 1 add string[i] to myList[0]
else to myList[1]
```

In the end, I would have 2 members in my list, each member having several strings.

I am not sure how I can add these strings to the members as the method [List(Of T).Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1.aspx) inserts members to the list and I do not want this.

Comment: Your list currently holds `string[]` which are string arrays. It's not clear if this is intended or you meant to hold a list of strings `List<string>`.

Comment: memebr 1 myList[0] will have string1, string2, etc, and the second member myList[1] will having another bunch of strings

Comment: ... i.e., a `List<List<string>>`

Comment: @Sunscreen: Why use an array?  will it always have exactly 2 members?

Comment: I just need 2 members. If there is another imlementation is very welcome...

Comment: @reinierpost Can you answer the question with this comment? I was implemented your way and it is clear, thanks a lot...

Answer (score 3):

From what I can see, you don't want a list of string arrays, you want a 2-element array of lists of strings:

```
var myList = new List<string>[] { new List<string>(), new List<string>() };
```

Now you should be able to implement the algorithm exactly as you specified.

Comment: It sounds promissing, and how can I add? possibly like that myList[0].Add() ??

Comment: Though I am using C# 2.0 and I cannot declare varcutom type... i sthere away to do it?

Comment: @Sunscreen: Then replace `var` with `List<string>[]`.

Comment: Again compalins that Iit cannot convert List<string>[] to List<string>[]

Comment: @Sunscreen: Can you copy the message in verbatim? `Cannot convert List<string>[] to List<string>[]` doesn't make sense...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5312/discussion-between-heinzi-and-sunscreen)

Comment: thanks a lot for the feedback. I implemented though this: List<List<string>>, creating two List<strings> it was very clear. Thanks a lot though...

Answer (score 3):

```
        var myList = new List<string>[] { new List<string>(), new List<string>() }; 

        for (int i = 0; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            if (i == 1)
                myList.Last().Add(i.ToString());
            else
                myList.First().Add(i.ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be also performed as List of List of string as below:

```
    List<List<string>> strList = new List<List<string>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (nNumber == 1)
            strList[0].Add(i.ToString());
        else
            strList[1].Add(i.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my csv parsing class, I have the following defined

`enum gic_rpt_columns { AGYDIV, STS, GICID, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, COVERAGE, DESCRIPTION , PREMIUM, RUNDATE, BILMO, EMPLOYERPERCENT };`

```
public class csv_parser
{
    .
    .
    .
    private string[]        m_column_headings;
    List<string[]>          m_csv_array = new List<string[]>();
    .
    .
    .
```

The following code will add my column headings and then the rows in the csv file

```
               using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(m_csv_path))
                {
                    parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
                    parser.SetDelimiters(",");

                    if (!parser.EndOfData)
                    {
                        m_column_headings = parser.ReadFields();
                        m_csv_array.Add(m_column_headings);
                    }

                    while (!parser.EndOfData)
                    {
                        string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
                        m_csv_array.Add(fields);
                        m_row_count++;
                    }
                }
```